# I need both spaces and plus sign to be preserved in jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I am posting textarea value which is picked up by jquery and sent to php backend. Here's the problem I'm facing: if I use `urldecode()` in php, the `+` sign is not shown and if I use `rawurldecode()` the multiple spaces between the words and the new lines are not preserved

//jquery

```
    $('#Btn').on('click', function f()
    {
var v=escape($("#postT").val());
    });
```

//HTML

```
        <textarea id="postT" name="postT"></textarea>
         <input type="button" name="subp" id="Btn" value="Post" />
```

//php

//if i use urldecode()

```
         if(isset($_REQUEST['v']))
          {
           $T_post=urldecode($_REQUEST['v']);
          }
          echo $T_post;
```

//if I enter textarea value as 'hi+hello'  result will be 'hi hello'. The + sign is not at all shown

//if i use rawurldecode()

```
           if(isset($_REQUEST['v']))
          {
           $T_post=rawurldecode($_REQUEST['v']);
          }
          echo $T_post;
```

//if I enter textarea value as 'hi        hello'  result will be 'hi hello'. only one space is shown instead of so many spaces between the words

But I want both things to happen like preserving as many spaces I have entered into textarea and showing the `+` sign as well.

thank you

Comment: What happens if you do a usual form post (via submit button) without any Javascript intervention before submit? Browser will do `encodeURIComponent(..)`, and PHP will decode percentile encoded values for you.

Comment: so what's the solution?

Answer (score 1):

var v = encodeURIComponent($("#postT").val());

Comment: with encodeURIComponent() ,there are two problems. first is if i use quotes like 'hi' it will show as \hi\ and second problem is it will not preserve multiple spaces